# ASP.NET MVC=> User Session/ Cookie / Talking to Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

I am not sure if I am doing this right but just wanted to know how to handle a loggedonuser in my system.

requirements

*User will login with a CompanyID, UserID and password

*We check if User can log in if so

*We store CompanyID and UserID inside the cookie so the loggedonuser can access areas of our site, we make a lot of calls to the db that require both company and user

Question: How do I communicate the loggedon user throughout my services?

My code - so you know what I am doing:

```
public interface IUserSession
{
    void SetClientStore(string LoginID, string Identifier); //store in cookie
    void Logout();
    string LoginID { get; private set; } //in cookie
    string CompanyIdentifier { get; private set; } //in cookie

}

public interface IAuthorizationService
{
    bool AuthenticateUser(string Identenfier, string LoginID, string password);
}

public class HandleAuthentication
{
    private readonly IUserSession _session;
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _auth;

    public HandleAuthentication(IUserSession session,
                                IAuthorizationService auth)
    {
        _session = session;
        _auth = auth;
    }

    public void AuthenticationUser(string Identenfier, string LoginID, string password)
    {
        if (_auth.AuthenticateUser(Identenfier, LoginID, password))
            _session.SetClientStore(LoginID, Identenfier);
        else
            _session.Logout();
    }
```

Should I get the current user in my base controller and pass it along everywhere? So all my services are not dependent on an interface ??

So in my base controller i create a property called:

```
public UserProfile MyProfile {get {return //something here;}}
```

then send this property to any service, use this property in any db calls etc. UserProfile would be a strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store any additional information into the userData part of the authentication cookie as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7297847/29407). Then you will use custom principal which will be injected into the User property accessible everywhere where you have an HttpContext. So inside controller actions you will have access to the User property (you could probably have a base controller which would expose a strongly typed version of it to the custom principal) and then pass along the information to the back-office services.

Comment: My problem/ issue is more with the backend services, that means I would pass in UserProfile to every potential service that needs it, in my case it would probably be a lot of them, I thought maybe passing an an interface would be better, is it?

Comment: @Haroon, well, you will have to populate this interface somewhere, right? This should happen in controller actions since it is there where you would have access to this information. So I would have my service methods take a model which contains the required information and it will be passed from actions.

Comment: would it not be better to work with an interface in my backend? Use Ninject to simply inject it throughout or is the approach you are recommending better?

Comment: @Haroon, yes, you could indeed configure NInject to pass an instance containing user data to the service layer if this information will be required by all methods. You just need to ensure that you have configured a per request life-cycle for your service objects.

Comment: per request life-cycle for my service objects? What does that mean? I want to have **UserProfile MyProfile { get; }** on my interface where in my implementation I will call the database and set up all sorts of information relevant to the current user, I dont want to be calling the database multiple times across services, that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Haroon, that means that your service should be instantiated by the container when the request begins and disposed at the end. It should not be reused. Otherwise, if you use singleton, your service will be instantiated only once (probably for the first request) and will be reused by all other subsequent requests and users which obviously is very bad if you decide to inject user information into it.

Comment: So the default bindings or InRequestScope is what I use, I understand that part. Thank you...

Comment: @Haroon, exactly, InRequestScope is what you need since the values will be read from the cookie available on each request.